# Writing a query method in Repository containing Key Value pairs to check against DB

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have metadata stored in a key/value table in SQL Server. I know this is bad way of storing the data but we couldn't avoid it. Users need to be able to give me an arbitrary set of key/value pairs and have me return the Template id that match their criteria. My application is a Spring boot with JPA enabled.

[Below is how it is saved in DB. Multiple Contexts differentiate a template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mlfy4.png)

Would like to know how does my repository method should be designed to get the correct Template id.

Have tried different ways but always getting both the templates for any data provided. Example like below I need to get only template 3

```
{
"Role":"PMGR",
"Country":"IN",
"Unit":"000737",
"Test":"VALUE2"
}
```

I would like to know the best way of doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> first create this split function

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String varchar(8000),@Delimiter char(1))        
returns @temptable TABLE (k varchar(8000),v varchar(8000))        
as        
begin        
    declare @idx int        
    declare @slice varchar(8000)        

    declare @c int;
    set @c=0;

    select @idx = 1        
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return        

    while @idx!= 0        
    begin        
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)        
        if @idx!=0        
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)        
        else        
            set @slice = @String        

        if(len(@slice)>0)
            begin  
            declare @k varchar(8000) =substring(@slice,2,charindex(':',@slice)-3)
            declare @v varchar(8000) =reverse(substring(reverse(@slice),2,charindex(':',reverse(@slice))-3))
            insert into @temptable(k,v )  
            values(ltrim(rtrim(replace(@k,'"',''))),ltrim(rtrim(@v)))        
            set @c=@c+1;
            end
        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)        
        if len(@String) = 0 break        
    end    
return        
end
```

> Then use this query

```
declare @param nvarchar(max)='"Role":"PMGR",
"Country":"IN",
"Unit":"000737",
"Test":"VALUE2"'


select t2.k,t2.v,t2.id from 
[dbo].[Split](REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@param, CHAR(9), ''), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''),',') as t1 -- re
inner join t2 -- your table
on t1.k=t2.k
and t1.v=t2.v

/*
CHAR(9)       - Tab
CHAR(10) - New Line
CHAR(13) - Carriage Return
*/
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, have tried your answer but the function is returning wrong result of the Param string. It is trimming off the few characters

Rol MGR
"Countr N
"Uni 00737
"Tes ALUE2

Comment: Sorry for that, I resolved slicing and increased key & value lengths for bigger strings and removed tabs and New lines and carriage return characters, and it worked fine for me